# Toggle link with its content Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code
http://jsfiddle.net/tdvtjqah/

```js
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
     var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
     $(".category").hide();
     $(selector).show();
 });



$('.inline-link a').click(function () {

 $('.inline-link').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-link">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-75">Category 75</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-76">Category 76</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-77">Category 77</a>
</div>

<div class="category cat-75">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
<div class="category cat-76">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
<div class="category cat-76">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
```

When you click on a link, I want its content display.

When you click on another link, its content display and the others hide.

I try to match links and categories with `[data-toggle]` but in my code, it does not work.

Thanks for  your help !

Comment: always post the relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the selector with dot or hash. In your case, you have defined them in class, so do like this:

```
$('.'+selector).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `selector` returns `cat-75`, which should be `.cat-75` (missing the dot). So, change the selector to `$("."+selector)`.

I changed it in the code:

```js
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
     var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
     $(".category").hide();
     $("."+selector).show();
        $(".inline-link .active").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-link">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-75">Category 75</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-76">Category 76</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-77">Category 77</a>
</div>

<div class="category cat-75">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
<div class="category cat-76">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
<div class="category cat-76">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
```

In your case, `a[data-toggle]` is the same as `.inline-link a`. I used that to combine both events. In case that should be, change the JS to:

```
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
        var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
        $(".category").hide();
        $("."+selector).show();
    });
$('.inline-link a').click(function () {
    $('.inline-link a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

```js
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
     var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
     $(".category").hide();
     $("."+selector).show();
 });
$('.inline-link a').click(function () {
 $('.inline-link a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-link">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-75">Category 75</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-76">Category 76</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-77">Category 77</a>
</div>

<div class="category cat-75">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
<div class="category cat-76">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
<div class="category cat-76">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.  
</div>
```

Comment: why not extra event? `.inline-link a` is not always `a[data-toggle]`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, true indeed, changed the answer, giving both options.

Answer (score 0):

While @**BhojendraNepal** has rightly pointed out the main problem with your code was that you were missing a **dot** (.) concatenated together with `selector` variable, I would just like to add one more thing: you probably don't need to use two different `click` handlers, one should be enough.

***Snippet:***

```js
$('.category').hide();
$('.inline-link a').click(function () {
    $('.inline-link').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.category').hide();
    $('.'+$(this).data('toggle')).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-link"> <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-75">Category 75</a>
 <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-76">Category 76</a>
 <a href="#" data-toggle="cat-77">Category 77</a>
</div>
<div class="category cat-75">Category 75: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.</div>
<div class="category cat-76">Category 76: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.</div>
<div class="category cat-77">Category 77: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore non eius voluptatem quo odio vitae dolor tenetur labore quia totam ipsum ad nulla amet quidem suscipit neque quam porro sunt.</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: After loading the page, I want the first category to show. How is it possible ?

Comment: Exact. Thanks ! I prefer do this instead $('.category').first().show();

Comment: Yup. That should also do. In fact, you can hide all of them first and then show the first one, all in one line. I think it can go something like this: `$('.category').hide().first().show();`.